# Comparing integers in JS

Tags: javascript, integer, comparison

I have two integers (`integerOne` and `integerTwo`) and I need to write a JavaScript program that outputs the larger one in the console.

The integers are defined like so:

```
let integerOne = 8; 
let integerTwo = 10;
```

And I'm expecting 10 to be printed as the output. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

We can use the > operator to return a boolean, and depending on the boolean we can use the ternary operator to print the output.

```
let integerOne = 8; 
let integerTwo = 10;
console.log(integerOne > integerTwo ? integerOne : integerTwo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple using ternary operator:

```
let integerOne = 8; 
let integerTwo = 10;

integerOne > integerTwo ? console.log(integerOne) : console.log(integerTwo);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a simple comparison statement to compare values. for example:

```
let integerOne = 8;
let integerTwo = 10;

if (integerOne > integerTwo) {
  console.log(integerOne);
} else {
  console.log(integerTwo);
}
```

The above example will print 10 on your console.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max):

```js
let i = 8; 
let j = 10;

console.log(
  Math.max(i, j) // => 10
)
```